# Backbone.js event is not fired

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I tried to use Backbone.js for one of my projects, but got a problem using view events.

The HTML file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="model.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

model.js code is

```
window.onload = function() {
    var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults: {
            name: "Test"
        }
    });

    var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
        tagName: "li",
        events: {
            "click li": "Show"
        },
        render: function() {
            this.el.innerHTML = this.model.get("name");
        },
        Show: function() {
            alert(this.model.get("name"));
        }
    });

    var model = new MyModel();
    var view = new MyView({model: model});
    view.render();

    document.getElementById("app").appendChild(view.el);
}
```

I get no errors, but the "Show" function is not fired on "li" click. What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are binding the click event to the (non-existant) "li" child of the element, rather than the li element itself.  Try this:

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    events: {
        "click": "Show"
    },
    render: function() {
        this.el.innerHTML = this.model.get("name");
    },
    Show: function() {
        alert(this.model.get("name"));
    }
});
```